# Horizontally scrollng div

Tags: html, touch, horizontal-scrolling

I am on a tight, self-imposed deadline to complete my first site by the end of the year. Right now, I am working on a horizontally scrolling div that includes "story blocks" and that can be scrolled with the mouse wheel or touch. Essentially, I would prefer something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awb3B.jpg) In this picture, the "story-blocks" scroll horizontally inside a div which assumes the remaining height of the page. Here is a *very* rough example of what I have been playing with in Codepen.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="scroll-container">
    <div class="story"> Story story story </div>
    <div class="story"> Story story story </div>
    <div class="story"> Story story story </div>
    <div class="story"> Story story story </div>
    <div class="story"> Story story story </div>
    <div class="story"> Story story story </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#scroll-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: /* Remaining Height on Page */;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden; }

#scroll-container div {
  display: inline-block; }

.story {
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px; }
```

[Here is the corresponding Codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wflEJ) What I am looking for, ideally, is to create this div that can scroll horizontally ala Windows 8, in which the user's up and down scrollwheel will scroll the div left and right. Of course, this may not be possible, but if it is I'd love to see it.

I have struggled with this element and have tried to do it on my own for a while now, but with New Year's Eve fast approaching, I am finally asking for a little help from the Stack Overflow community. Thank you in advance and happy almost New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
html, body{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Even more, you can style it. Here is how to do it for webkit browsers like Chrome and Safari:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

It looks much better, right? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FlzJH

Comment: How would I modify this code to have multiple rows of story blocks? I know the no-wrap modifier removes the multiple rows, but I'd like to have those blocks make use of the height they have? Thank you for the response/

Comment: Not exactly, I mean having the story blocks run over that one line yet still being able to scroll horizontally. Like in the picture above where there are 3 separate rows but all of them are still scrolling horizontally.

Comment: @DanielHerzig Then add one more row to that codepen? Or do you don't want that scrollbar? Do you want to scroll rows individually or all at once?

Comment: I would like rows that scroll all at once. In the current Codepen there is only one row that scrolls.

Comment: Hm, I made here example of three rows scrolling at once (enlarge that bottom area to see whole content): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FlzJH

Comment: @DanielHerzig: I'm glad I could helped. I wouldn't mind accepting it as answer then also.